# Tomcat 7 Start up problem in Eclispse for maven project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I m getting this intermittent problem in eclipse, when i try to run a maven project in tomcat

Details are as follows :

- Eclipse version : 3.6
- Maven version : 2.2.1
- Tomcat version : 7

Error log :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1362)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3712)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4216)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

Deleting and Recreating the server solves the problem, but still i would like to know why this error is created.

Answer (score 2):

This error usually occurs when Spring misses a jar file on the classpath. The main reason for this is that Eclipse not always deploys a project correctly to its Tomcat server. Instead of deleting the server, you can also clean the server and redeploy the application.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your reply. Well my problem was fixed by doing a `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error

I added my spring library in deployment assembly and build path of the project.

I think your server did not detect the library and restarting it made the server check for the build paths.